# Angular 2 Router link active with two links activating

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, router

I have a project with the following routes:

```
{ path: '', component: GamesListingComponent },

    { path: 'inicio', component: HomeComponent },

    { path: 'listar',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'fabricantes', component: ManufacturesListingComponent },
            { path: 'plataformas', component: PlatformsListingComponent },
            { path: 'usuarios', component: UsersListingComponent },
            { path: 'jogos', component: GamesListingComponent },
            { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    },

    { path: 'cadastrar',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'fabricantes', component: ManufacturesRegisterComponent },
            { path: 'plataformas', component: PlatformsRegisterComponent },
            { path: 'usuarios', component: UsersRegisterComponent },
            { path: 'jogos', component: GamesRegisterComponent },
            { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    },

    { path: '**', component: GamesListingComponent }
```

And I would like the routerLinkActive to be enabled only by the name of the child routes, for example:

When accessing "/listar/jogos" and "/cadastrar/jogos", wanted to be accessed these two routes the same routerLinkActive was active.

header.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="text-center title"><a [routerLink]="['/inicio']">Lightning Games</a></p>
    <p class="text-center">A sua loja de jogos desde o seu primeiro dia</p>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/inicio']">Início <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/listar', 'plataformas']">Plataformas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/listar', 'fabricantes']">Fabricantes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/listar', 'usuarios']">Usuários</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/listar', 'jogos']">Jogos</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add your html code as well. It sounds like you need to add
`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"`

Comment: I updated the post, should I enter this command at home active? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If you want your route to be active for **ONE EXACT ROUTE**

Adding `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` will make the active class only apply to exact route matches.

If that is what you want, then update your `<li>` tags as follows:

```
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
   <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/inicio']">Início <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

2. If you want to have your route link active for **MULTIPLE SIMILAR ROUTES**

Look at this Plunkr code that I have modified from one of the official Angular routing examples. https://plnkr.co/edit/wWyVfxDHbSA8tYcpsNsF?p=preview

Take note of two things:

- In app-routing.module.ts you will see that there are two similar routes:

`{ path: 'heroes/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }`

- In app.component.ts (in the embedded template code) you will see that their is a route:

`<routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>`

This route matches BOTH of the paths set in app-routing.module.ts - this means that it will have the active class applied for any route that starts with **/heroes**

**UPDATE:**

In your example, you can do this by changing your routing to the following:

app.routes.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: GamesListingComponent },

  { path: 'inicio', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

  { path: 'jogos', component: GamesListingComponent },
  { path: 'fabricantes', component: ManufacturesListingComponent },
  { path: 'plataformas', component: PlatformsListingComponent },
  { path: 'usuarios', component: UsersListingComponent },

  { path: 'jogos/cadastrar', component: GamesRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'fabricantes/cadastrar', component: ManufacturesRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'plataformas/cadastrar', component: PlatformsRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'usuarios/cadastrar', component: UsersRegisterComponent },

  { path: '**', component: GamesListingComponent }

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`
```

header.component.html

```
        <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/inicio']">Início <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/plataformas']">Plataformas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/fabricantes']">Fabricantes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/usuarios']">Usuários</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" >
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/jogos']">Jogos</a>
        </li>
```

xxx-listing.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['/jogos/cadastrar']" class="btn btn-primary">
  Novo Jogo
</a>
```

Comment: It still does not work, when I put "/listar/jogos" it brings the asset, but when I enter "/cadastrar/jogos" it is disabled.

Comment: Hi @HenriqueBuzin, I thought that was what you wanted. I will update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, I modified everything to agree and it was not, when I put "jogos/listar" the active works, but when I put "jogos/cadastrar" no, would there be anything else I could do? I heard about understanding the lick active router, but I'm not sure what it would look like. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HenriqueBuzin - you will need to create a plunkr or downloadable example of your code for me to help any further. If you post the link here I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it available, it's the doubt version, in case you need the version with the modifications of your last answer just let me know that I have it available too. Thank you.

Comment: Files: https://github.com/HenriqueBuzin/lightning-games/tree/master/client/src/app

Comment: @HenriqueBuzin Please confirm if the updated answer resolves your problem.

Comment: How to add an active class to the drop down button when we navigate to any nav item pages in the  dropdown menu items?

Comment: To me, route "" was been activated even if i was on "blablabla" route. Just replace "" to the real home path, something like "home". Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to active your route for two links then change your html file like this,

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light'>
   <div class='width-100'>
     <div class='float-left'> 
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>   
      <li><a class='nav-link' [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"[routerLink]="['/abc']">Abc</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/def']" >Def
               <a routerLink="/ghi"></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div> 
   </div>
</nav>
```

And define your routes in your app-module.ts file like this,

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,  
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      //, canDeactivate : ['canDeactivateCreateEmployee']},
      { path: 'abc', component: AbcComponent },
      { path: 'def', component: DefComponent },
      { path: 'ghi',  component: GhiComponent},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'AbcComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'AbcComponent', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ],
```

This will make single RouterLinkActive for two URL (def,ghi)